# Encrypting efficiently on mobile devices

Tags: encryption, mobile

What is the most efficient industry-strength encryption method/library for mobile devices?  Ideally, I would like it to be endorsed by the US government for transmitting sensitive data.

I have a number of mass-produced mobile devices, and I want to start encrypting
their satellite and GSM communication.  The firmware is in C.  My concern is that the battery won't last once I start encrypting.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Way to platform specific...

Many ARM architectures have native, instruction level support for cryptography.
However, you should understand that you may be able to encrypt the message, but most of the message passing infrastructure is in-the-clear. Second, the standard recommendation for cryptography is NOT to implement it yourself-your implementation WILL be the part that fails first.

In the interest of academic study, I will ask you to consider [All the AES You Need on Cortex-M3 and M4](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/714.pdf) by Peter Schwabe and Ko Stoffelen

As for power concerns, the display and cellular modem are by far the largest factors.

Comment: Could you clarify what "most of the message passing infrastructure" means?  Does it mean that only certain parts of every message are encrypted?  Also, the instruction set, in my particular case, is ARM7TDMI-S.